# Is this a graph problem or something else?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization, graph-algorithm

I've come across a problem that at first looks like the well known maximum sum subarray problem but there's a twist that makes things much more complex.

*Suppose you have two arrays each containing the same amount of "1"s and "-1"s. Additionally, suppose each "1" in the first array has a corresponding or sibling "1" in the second array. Same for each "-1". The task is to find the optimal subarrays, one in the first array and one in the second, such that their combined sum is the largest (maximal) with the added constraint that an element in one subarray only counts towards the sum if the other subarray contains its sibling.*

Anyone know what kind of problem this is? It looks like it could be a graph problem in disguise but I'm not sure which. If there's optimal substructure here I don't see that either. I know it can be solved by complete search but surely there's a faster way.

Below is an example of the setup to the problem.

[image]

Here the optimal solution is subarray [2..9] in the first array with subarray [4..9] in the second array for a sum of 8.

Comment: How do you know number is sibling of other in two arrays? have you stored this data somewhere?

Comment: A simple way to store that data would be for each element in the array to be a tuple that contains the number along with the index of the sibling in the other array.

Comment: This can be formulated as a Mixed-Integer Program or a Constraint Programming problem. Not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Integer programming is **NP-complete** right? So unless I feel like solving P=NP I can assume there is no polynomial time solution for a problem like this? If it can be formulated as an integer programming problem does that mean it is **only** as such or is there a chance you could formulate it a different way that allows for a faster solution?

Comment: It is surely not in NP class. The brute force is `O(n^4)`.

Comment: I think the brute force is `O(n^3)`. For each subarray in the first array - `O(n^2)` - you can use something along the lines of Kadane's algorithm - `O(n)` - to find the best subarray in the second array.